# Removing/Replacing multiple special character in filename using RegEx in flex

Tags: regex, apache-flex

I want to remove or replace special character in file name.

Heres my code, it works in replacing single special character.

```
// Remove special characters from the name.
var excludeChars:RegExp = /&/gi;
var revisedname:String=new String();

revisedname=newname.replace(excludeChars,"");
newname=new String();
newname=revisedname;

//sample Output: &filename --> filename
```

but how to do this in replacing multiple special character using RegExp. How to declare multiple RegEx.

for example:

```
// &file%name# --> filename
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: How about `[^\w]` instead of `&` in the regex?

Comment: What is [^\w]? im sorry I dont know that.

Comment: Negated character class for any non-`\w` character, which is anything that's not a-z, 0-9, or an underscore

Comment: Yes I tried it, it works, thank you so much. but how about I want to replace only this & % # ^ special Character? Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: @JacxToi, sure, you can use `[&%#^]` for that.

Comment: @Qtax, thank you so much for your help. it works!.. Thanks also Explosion Pills..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to replace `&%#^`, you can create a character class for just those:

```
var excludeChars:RegExp = /[&%#^]/g;
```

The `[]` notation creates a character class which means "match any of these characters."  The `g` makes it global.